# ERROR EN JAVA CON BOOTSTRAP CLASS PATH

Tags: java, bootstrap, netbeans

Actualmente estoy creando un proyecto en Netbeans, pero al momento de ejecutarlo me sale este error, como puedo solucionarlo??

warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 8
C:\Users\heidy\MISIONTIC\JAVA\EJERCICIOS EN CLASE\DAO57-V4\CASO4_DAO57\src\modelo\EstudianteDaoImp.java:25: error: cannot access Archivo
public Archivo miArchivo;
bad class file: C:\Users\heidy\MISIONTIC\JAVA\EJERCICIOS EN CLASE\DAO57-V4\CASO4_DAO57\build\classes\modelo\persistencia\Archivo.class
class file contains wrong class: modelo.Persistencia.Archivo
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
Note: C:\Users\heidy\MISIONTIC\JAVA\EJERCICIOS EN CLASE\DAO57-V4\CASO4_DAO57\src\modelo\persistencia\Archivo.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
1 warning
BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya resolví el error, dejo la solución por si llega a servirle a alguien:

Se debía a un error en la configuración a continuación dejo el link con el paso a paso

https://complete-concrete-concise.com/programming/java/warning-options-bootstrap-class-path-not-set-in-conjunction-with-source-1-5/